# SSMS select same row from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables like so:

table1:

```
    ID      Date1         Date2
    
    1       2020-04-14    2020-04-06
    1       2020-02-12    2020-04-06
    1       2020-03-03    2020-04-06
```

table2:

```
    ID     Date1          Date2
    1      2020-04-16     2020-04-10
    1      2020-04-14     2020-04-06
```

I need to update Date2 column in  table1 with null value where the row doesn't match with table 2. So my output for table1 needs to look like:

```
    ID      Date1       Date2
    1       2020-04-14    2020-04-06
    1       2020-02-12    NULL
    1       2020-03-03    NULL
```

I have initially tried wiping out all values for Date2 in table1 and updating using the below code:

```sql
UPDATE table1
    SET t1.Date2= t2.Date2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    AND CAST(t1.Date1 AS DATE) = CAST(t2.Date1 AS DATE)
```

But the above code updates all rows for Date2 in table1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do also the ids need to match?

Comment: Yes, the IDs need to match

Comment: In your sample data the ids don't match for the row in Table1 that is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join and update the unmatched rows:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Date2 = null
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date1 = t1.Date1
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bb5cc07105cbad23dfbaa4fb634e4f8).

You can do the same without a join, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Date2 = null
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = Table1.ID AND t2.Date1 = Table1.Date1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7dd268a079fb1f1e01eda6270a11e488).

Results:

```
> ID | Date1      | Date2     
> -: | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | 2020-04-14 | 2020-04-06
>  1 | 2020-02-12 | null      
>  1 | 2020-03-03 | null
```

Comment: I did not need the last condition on date2 for the on clause.Works perfect otherwise, thanks.

Comment: @user10 check also the query with NOT EXISTS. It could perform better.